# Strtotime php with date to start

Tags: php, strtotime

Ok, it's works:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+ 30 day"))
```

But, if I to use a date defined, how can I do? example:

```
date('2015-04-27', strtotime("+ 30 day"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking here, are you asking how to add 30 days to a specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do here, but if you are asking how you would go about adding 30 days to a specific date you could do it in one of these ways:

```
<?php
$today = '2015-04-27';
$plusThirtyDays = strtotime($today . ' + 30 days');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $plusThirtyDays); // 2015-05-27
```

Or this way:

```
<?php
$today = new DateTime('2015-04-27');
$plusThirtyDays = new DateInterval("P30D");
$today->add($plusThirtyDays);
echo $today->format('Y-m-d'); // 2015-05-27
```

Checkout the docs below:
[`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
[`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)